# Debian and Systemd: breaking ordering cycle error

Tags: linux, embedded, systemd, d-bus

I'm a new embedded developer

I'm trying to make [systemd 37](http://repository.timesys.com/buildsources/s/systemd/systemd-3/) work with freescale vybrid board (A5 and M4) running on [linux-3.0](http://www.timesys.com/)

After boot with some breaking ordering cycle error, I check with

> ps ax | grep dbus

it prints nothing

I don't know what things break ordering cycle ?

```
Linux version 3.0.15-ts-armv7l (longlt3@bu16vybrid) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Timesys 20140217) ) #1 Mon Mar 31 18:49:33 ICT 2014
CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc051] revision 1 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d
CPU: VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
Machine: Freescale MVF TOWER VF700 Board
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
On node 0 totalpages: 32768
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 804caeb0, node_mem_map 804eb000
  DMA zone: 256 pages used for memmap
  DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
  DMA zone: 32512 pages, LIFO batch:7
pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 32512
Kernel command line: mem=128M console=ttymxc1,115200 ip=dhcp root=/opt/rfs/longlt3 rw nfsroot=192.168.1.1:/opt/rfs/longlt3 panic=10 init=/bin/systemd
PID hash table entries: 512 (order: -1, 2048 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Memory: 128MB = 128MB total
Memory: 124872k/124872k available, 6200k reserved, 0K highmem
Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
    DMA     : 0xf4600000 - 0xffe00000   ( 184 MB)
    vmalloc : 0x88800000 - 0xf2000000   (1688 MB)
    lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0x88000000   ( 128 MB)
    modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
      .init : 0x80008000 - 0x80031000   ( 164 kB)
      .text : 0x80031000 - 0x80497000   (4504 kB)
      .data : 0x80498000 - 0x804cb9c0   ( 207 kB)
       .bss : 0x804cb9e4 - 0x804ea2a4   ( 123 kB)
SLUB: Genslabs=13, HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
NR_IRQS:432
MVF GPIO hardware
sched_clock: 32 bits at 66MHz, resolution 15ns, wraps every 65075ms
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Calibrating delay loop... 262.96 BogoMIPS (lpj=1314816)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
devtmpfs: initialized
NET: Registered protocol family 16
mcf_edma: Initialized successfully
 fec_get_mac_addr 0 0 0 0 0 0
L310 cache controller enabled
l2x0: 8 ways, CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x02060000, Cache size: 524288 B
IMX usb wakeup probe. id=1
the wakeup pdata is 0x860d62c0
IMX usb wakeup probe. id=0
the wakeup pdata is 0x860d6400
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.24.
Switching to clocksource pit
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
TCP reno registered
UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Static Power Management for Freescale Vybrid
cpaddr = 88820000 suspend_iram_base=88808000 iram_paddr 3f070000
PM driver module loaded
JFFS2 version 2.2. (NAND) \xffffffc2\xffffffa9 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
msgmni has been set to 243
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 60x34
fb0: Layer0 fb device registered successfully.
fb1:  fb device registered successfully.
fb2:  fb device registered successfully.
fb3:  fb device registered successfully.
Serial: MVF driver
IMX UART EDMA enabled
IMX UART FIFO enabled
imx-uart.1: ttymxc1 at MMIO 0x40028000 (irq = 94) is a IMX
console [ttymxc1] enabled
brd: module loaded
FSL NFC MTD nand Driver 1.0
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0x2c, Chip ID: 0xca (Micron NAND 256MiB 3,3V 16-bit)
Bad block table found at page 131008, version 0x01
Bad block table found at page 130944, version 0x01
nand_read_bbt: Bad block at 0x000000000000
nand_read_bbt: Bad block at 0x000000020000
Registering NAND as whole device
Faraday DSPI DMA addr: Tx-0xffdff000[0x8617c000], Rx-0xffdfe000[0x861d1000]
DSPI: Coldfire master initialized
FEC Ethernet Driver
fec_enet_mii_bus: probed
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
add wake up source irq 108
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: irq 108, io base 0x400b4000
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
ARC USBOTG Device Controller driver (1 August 2005)
add wake up source irq 107
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
input: crtouch_ts as /devices/platform/imx-i2c.0/i2c-0/0-0049/input/input0
snvs_rtc snvs_rtc.0: rtc core: registered snvs_rtc as rtc0
i2c /dev entries driver
lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 252 
IR NEC protocol handler initialized
IR RC5(x) protocol handler initialized
IR RC6 protocol handler initialized
IR JVC protocol handler initialized
IR Sony protocol handler initialized
IR RC5 (streamzap) protocol handler initialized
IR LIRC bridge handler initialized
Linux video capture interface: v2.00
usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
USB Video Class driver (v1.1.0)
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
sgtl5000 0-000a: Device with ID register 0 is not a sgtl5000
sgtl5000 0-000a: asoc: failed to probe CODEC sgtl5000.0-000a: -19
asoc: failed to instantiate card sgtl5000-sai: -19
ALSA device list:
  No soundcards found.
TCP cubic registered
NET: Registered protocol family 10
IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 5 rev 1
snvs_rtc snvs_rtc.0: setting system clock to 1970-01-07 07:38:51 UTC (545931)
eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver [Micrel KS8041] (mii_bus:phy_addr=1:00, irq=-1)
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
PHY: 1:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Sending DHCP requests ., OK
IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 192.168.1.1, my address is 192.168.1.32
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, addr=192.168.1.32, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.1.1,
     host=192.168.1.32, domain=bu16vybrid, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=192.168.1.1, rootserver=192.168.1.1, rootpath=
VFS: Mounted root (nfs filesystem) on device 0:12.
Freeing init memory: 164K
systemd[1]: systemd 37 running in system mode. (+PAM -LIBWRAP -AUDIT -SELINUX +SYSVINIT -LIBCRYPTSETUP; debian)
systemd[1]: Set hostname to <twr_vf600>.
systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from random generator.
systemd[1]: /etc/mtab is not a symlink or not pointing to /proc/self/mounts. This is not supported anymore. Please make sure to replace this file by a symlink to avoid incorrect or misleading mount(8) output.
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/udev-control.socket:10] Unknown lvalue 'PassCredentials' in section 'Socket'. Ignoring.
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/udev-kernel.socket:10] Unknown lvalue 'PassCredentials' in section 'Socket'. Ignoring.
systemd[1]: [/etc/init.d/udevd:4] Failed to add LSB Provides name udev.service, ignoring: File exists
systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to sockets.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to dbus.socket/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to sysinit.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to local-fs.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to udevd.service/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to basic.target/start
systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job dbus.socket/start
systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to sysinit.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to local-fs.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to udevd.service/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to basic.target/start
systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service/start
systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to sysinit.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to local-fs.target/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to udevd.service/start
systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to basic.target/start
systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job local-fs.target/start
systemd-vconsole-setup[490]: /bin/loadkeys failed with error code 1.
systemd-vconsole-setup[490]: /bin/setfont failed with error code 1.
at entry, bookeeping_data not initialized
bookeeping_data= 0x888c0000, VIRT_TO_MQX(bookeeping_data)= 0x3f040000
.init_string = mccisrd
bookeeping_data->signal_queue_head[0]= 0x00000000, ->signal_queue_tail[0]= 0x00000000
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][0] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][1] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][2] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][3] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][4] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][5] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][6] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][7] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][8] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=0][9] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
bookeeping_data->signal_queue_head[1]= 0x00000000, ->signal_queue_tail[1]= 0x00000000
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][0] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][1] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][2] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][3] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][4] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][5] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][6] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][7] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][8] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
&bookeeping_data->signals_received[core=1][9] .type= unknow type, .destination=[22, 33, 44]
mcc registered major=251, sizeof(struct mcc_bookeeping_struct)=10880
udevd[502]: starting version 181
```

After run this cmd

> rm -rf /etc/init.d/* && systemctl reboot

I have this log

```
systemd[1]: Set hostname to <twr_vf600>.
systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from random generator.
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/udev-kernel.socket:10] Unknown lvalue 'PassCredentials' in section 'Socket'. Ignoring.
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/udev-control.socket:10] Unknown lvalue 'PassCredentials' in section 'Socket'. Ignoring.
Starting Runtime Directory...
Starting File System Check on Root Device...
Starting Remount API VFS...
Starting Media Directory...
Starting Lock Directory...
Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
Starting Setup Virtual Console...
Started Security File System.
Started Debug File System.
Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Started POSIX Message Queue File System.
Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Started Huge Pages File System.
mcc registered major=251, sizeof(struct mcc_bookeeping_struct)=10880
Starting Syslog Kernel Log Buffer Bridge...
Started Syslog Kernel Log Buffer Bridge.
Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
systemd-vconsole-setup[501]: /bin/loadkeys failed with error code 1.
systemd-vconsole-setup[501]: /bin/setfont failed with error code 1.
Started Runtime Directory.
Started File System Check on Root Device.
Started Remount API VFS.
Started Media Directory.
Started Lock Directory.
Started Setup Virtual Console.
udevd[511]: starting version 181
Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Started Load Kernel Modules.
Started Configuration File System.
Started FUSE Control File System.
Starting Remount Root FS...
Starting STDOUT Syslog Bridge...
Started STDOUT Syslog Bridge.
systemd[1]: remount-rootfs.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=32
mount[560]: mount: / not mounted or bad option
Starting Remount Root FS failed, see 'systemctl status remount-rootfs.service' for details.
systemd[1]: Unit remount-rootfs.service entered failed state.
Starting /tmp...  
Started /tmp.
Starting Load Random Seed...
Starting Recreate Volatile Files and Directories...
Started Load Random Seed.
Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Started Recreate Volatile Files and Directories.
Starting Login Service...
Starting Permit User Sessions...
Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
systemd-logind[788]: New seat seat0.
Started Permit User Sessions.
Starting Serial Getty on ttymxc1...
Started Serial Getty on ttymxc1.
Started Login Service.
Starting Getty on tty1...
Started Getty on tty1.
Starting Notify Audit System and Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
systemd[1]: Startup finished in 4s 272ms 677us (kernel) + 3s 46ms 184us (userspace) = 7s 318ms 861us.

Distribution built using LinuxLink by Timesys
Kernel 3.0.15-ts-armv7l for armv7l
twr_vf600 login: root
login[801]: pam_securetty(login:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
login[801]: pam_lastlog(login:session): file /var/log/lastlog created
login[801]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by LOGIN(uid=0)
login[810]: ROOT LOGIN  on '/dev/ttymxc1'
```

No more breaking ordering cycle error, I have dbus-daemon is running too, but any service in init.d has gone away (of course)

This is list of file in /etc/init.d

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1093 Apr  3  2014 S90-demo-heartbeat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1092 Apr  3  2014 S90-demo-led-blink
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1091 Apr  3  2014 S90-demo-lowpower
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   50 Apr  3  2014 S99-pam-runonce
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2845 Apr  3  2014 autofsd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1956 Apr  3  2014 dbus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1893 Apr  3  2014 fuse
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  636 Apr  3  2014 glib-compile-schemas
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  772 Apr  3  2014 modules
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  677 Apr  3  2014 mount
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  943 Apr  3  2014 network
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2370 Apr  3  2014 openssh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  583 Apr  3  2014 pam
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  585 Apr  3  2014 pwconv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1611 Apr  3  2014 rsyslog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1494 Apr  3  2014 sysklogd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5660 Apr  3  2014 udevd
```

After I remove glib-compile-schemas, dbus boot look normal

This is content of glib-compile-schemas

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 71 29
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          glib-compile-schemas
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start glib-compile-schemas at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by glib-compile-schemas.
# X-Start-Before:    x
# X-Stop-After:      
# X-Timesys-Start-Number:  71
# X-Timesys-Stop-Number:  29
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

case "$1" in
        start)
                glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas >/dev/null 2>&1
        ;;
        stop)
        ;;
        *)
                echo "$0 [start|stop]"
        ;;
esac
```

Why this script make breaking error on systemd ?

Any comments or answers would be very valuable to me

Thanks

Comment: Where does the `udevd.service` file come from?  I think you either need to add `DefaultDependencies=no` there, or remove that file (perhaps using `systemd-udev.service` and removing `/etc/init.d/udev`?)

Comment: yeah. I just fix this issue by switching to newer systemd version, it's 37 to 43. Now my systemd is stay on /usr/lib/systemd/system. With this version, my system boot look faster and more stable but some service in /etc/init.d does not boot, eg: /etc/init.d/S50-openssh. Now my other question is: how to write a complex systemd service file? because openssh always check key and folder exists before run. Should I create a new question?

Comment: Yes, you should create a new question for each question you have :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just switch to newer systemd version (eg: v43) These issues will be fixed, no cycle exists any more

p/s: I think all issue above come from conflict between sysvinit (/etc/init.d/) and systemd.

I still wonder about how systemd using sysvinit scripts, where did they start?

I cannot find any code in /usr/lib/systemd/system to start sysvinit script. Should I create a new question or start it right here?

and forgive about my ugly English

Comment: Yes, that should be a separate question