# generic methodology to debug ordering cycles in systemd

Tags: systemd

I am aware of [following thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123143/how-to-find-what-thing-make-a-cycle-in-systemd) and supposedly an [answer to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122889/debian-and-systemd-breaking-ordering-cycle-error). Except an answer is not an answer in generic sense. It tells what the problem was in one particular case, but not in general.

My question is: is there a way to debug ordering cycles in a **generic** way? E.g.: is there a command which will describe the cycle and what links one unit to another?

For example, I have following in `journalctl -b` (please disregard date, my system has no RTC to sync time with):

```
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on sysinit.target/start
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Found dependency on cvol.service/start
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Found dependency on basic.target/start
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Found dependency on sockets.target/start
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Found dependency on dbus.socket/start
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job local-fs.target/start
Jan 01 00:00:07 host0 systemd[1]: Job local-fs.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
```

where cvol.service (the one that got introduced, and which breaks the cycle) is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount Crypto Volume
After=boot.mount
Before=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cryptsetup open /dev/*** cvol --key-file /boot/***

[Install]
WantedBy=home.mount
WantedBy=root.mount
WantedBy=usr-local.mount
```

According to journalctl, cvol.service wants basic.service, except that it doesn't, at least not obviously. Is there a command which would demonstrate where this link is derived from? And in general, is there a command, which would find the cycles and show where each link in the cycle originates?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can visualise the cycle with the commands `systemd-analyze verify` , `systemd-analyze dot` and the [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) `dot` tool:

```
systemd-analyze verify default.target |&
perl -lne 'print $1 if m{Found.*?on\s+([^/]+)}' |
xargs --no-run-if-empty systemd-analyze dot |
dot -Tsvg >cycle.svg
```

You should see something like this:

[image]

Here you can see the cycle: `c.service->b.service->a.service->c.service`

```
Color legend: 
    black     = Requires
    dark blue = Requisite
    dark grey = Wants
    red       = Conflicts
    green     = After
```

**Links:**

- [systemd-analyze(1)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html)
- [dot(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dot)

Comment: `systemd-analyze verify` does not exist here on a debian 8 install.

Comment: @sjas, `systemd-analyze verify` [available](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/1d3bc0177a19) since `v216`. try `systemd-verify`. Does it exist?

Comment: hm, it does not exist on Jessie: https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-systemd/systemd.git/tree/debian/systemd.install?h=jessie

Comment: `systemd-analyze verify default.target` on its own does a decent job in showing the loop...

Comment: A better option for dot `dot -Tx11`. So you don't have to open a separate viewer.

Comment: This shows all the services making it really hard to pin point the cycle in question

Answer (score 27):

> Is there a command which would demonstrate where this link is derived from?

The closest you can do is `systemctl show -p Requires,Wants,Requisite,BindsTo,PartOf,Before,After cvol.service`, which will show the resulting (effective) dependency lists for a given unit.

> is there a command, which would find the cycles and show where each link in the cycle originates?

To my knowledge, there is no such command. Actually systemd offers nothing to aid in debugging ordering cycles (sigh).

> According to journalctl, cvol.service wants basic.service, except that it doesn't, at least not obviously.

First, the requirement dependencies (`Wants=`, `Requires=`, `BindsTo=` etc.) are independent of ordering dependencies (`Before=` and `After=`). What you see here is an *ordering* dependency cycle, i. e. it has nothing to do with `Wants=` etc.

Second, there is a number of "default dependencies" created between units of certain types. They are controlled by [`DefaultDependencies=`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#DefaultDependencies=) directive in the `[Unit]` section (which is *enabled by default*).

In particular, unless this directive is explicitly disabled, any `.service`-type unit gets implicit `Requires=basic.target` and `After=basic.target` dependencies, which is exactly what you see. This is documented in [systemd.service(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Description).

Comment: Command you quoted worked perfectly, and indeed revealed dependency on basic.target. It's a shame that the toolset for systemctl is so lacking, but oh well, it's a new project

Comment: @galets: Judging from my experience, there are very few examples of such shortage... Maybe someday I'll get around increasing verbosity of the cycle reporter, adding some useful information to the log.

Meanwhile, actually, you may use `systemd-analyze verify UNIT` to check unit's correctness. Behind the scenes, this command creates a virtual systemd instance and tries to load given UNIT as the initial transaction (as if it was `default.target`). This will not reveal any new information (compared to logs), but at least you won't have to reboot with the unit enabled to see if it fails.

Comment: systemd request for enhancement (RFE): [increase verbosity of the cycle reporter](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3834)

Answer (score 5):

step 1: run verification command for default.target

```
systemd-analyze verify default.target
```

step 2: observe which service or target mentioned in the message **"systemd Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job"** and display it's complete dependency list

```
systemctl show -p Requires,Wants,Requisite,BindsTo,PartOf,Before,After <service or target name mentioned in the "breaking cycle" message>
```

step 3: look at "after" and "before" groups inside the service or target file usually defined in

```
/lib/systemd/system
```

and find the services or targets well known to be sequential but are in outbound order for this one.

example:

```
dbus.service
```

is usually marked **"after"**

```
multi-user.target
```

but **"before"**

```
sockets.target
```

such dependency could be easily observed by calling

```
systemctl list-dependencies default.target
```

however if the file

```
/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service
```

contain lines like:

```
Before=multi-user.target
```

or

```
After=sockets.target
```

or both simultaneously, means dbus.service is defined outbound and it's causing an systemd endless cycle.

the **cure** is simple - change word **"After"** to **"Before"** and vice-versa if necessary.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443708/why-does-systemd-report-attempted-to-remove-disk-file-system-when-verify-is