# Debian systemd boot error with macspoofing: job sockets.target/start deleted to break [...]

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

What I did is adding macspoofing at every boot, following this guide at exactly this section: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing#macchanger
(I'm on Debian Testing)
Everything works correctly, both the internet connection and macchanger does his job, anyway at each boot systemd gives me two errors:

```
systemd[1]: networking.service: Job networking.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
systemd[1]: sockets.target: Job sockets.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with macspoof@wls1.service/start
```

What should I do?

EDIT: on a second reboot the macspoof message was replaced by dnscrypt (I had it installed too, before the macchanger) and on a third reboot only one message showed up, that was the networking.service one. So there's some mess in those services order, how to manage with this stuff?

EDIT 2: well, I solved adding a macchanger script to /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the service file that you wrote, please edit your original question with this. (Should have been a comment but I don't have the permission).

The base issue is that your service file has created a loop in desired startup order. Example: systemd wants to start `a` first, then `b`, then `c`, but `a` wants to start after `c`.
I would suspect that the two guilty lines are the `BindsTo` and `After`, since it makes it part of the same service that it wants to wait on.

However, you can follow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193854/148494) with `cvol.service` replaced with your `macspoof@wls1.service`.
Relevant command: `systemctl show -p Requires,Wants,Requisite,BindsTo,PartOf,Before,After macspoof@wls1.service`

Descriptions for keywords can be found [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: As I said, the only thing I did is following that guide with macchanger, so the only file I created is the one present in that link.

Comment: Okay, without knowing how debian names their services it's a bit hard to see if that's fully alright or if you should have modified it, but that you have to find out by yourself. Did the rest of my answer help you however? It is based on your log snippet and archlinux link, and is still valid after your edit.