# Why does systemd report "Attempted to remove disk file system" when "verify" is used to check a file syntax?

Tags: systemd

`systemd` ships the `systemd-analyze` command which has a `verify` function that allows you to check the syntax of a `systemd` unit file.

However, when I ran it today using `systemd` v238, I get a message back that a disk file system was attmpted to be deleted. What's going on?

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/my.timer
Attempted to remove disk file system, and we can't allow that
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This behavior is  [due to a bug in at least systemd 237 and 238](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8592).

From the bug report:

> systemd-analyze creates a directory named /tmp/systemd-temporary-XXXX. /tmp is a real, physical directory on my machine
>
> when rm_rf_children is called, for manager cleanup, it has a safety that prevents it from removing physical files unless explicitely told to do so.

While the diagnostic message is scary, it is thankfully about a temporary directory,
not telling you that it tried to do `rm -rf /`.