# Boot/systemd problem in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have Ubuntu MATE 16.04.5 running on Raspberry Pi.
I did a apt update/upgrade to install 18 upgraded packages but the system failed on reboot.

It entered emergency mode and on entering Ctl-D I could boot as normal and everything works as normal!

The only problem I could see is is dependencies in systemd

```
[Sun Nov 18 17:34:57 2018] systemd[1]: sockets.target: Job sockets.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
[Sun Nov 18 17:34:57 2018] systemd[1]: paths.target: Job paths.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
[Sun Nov 18 17:34:57 2018] systemd[1]: nfs-mountd.service: Job nfs-mountd.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with nfs-server.service/start
```

I could restore from backup, but wonder if this is a known issue, or just a random failure?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a hard reboot and see it the problem recurs.  If it doesn't, this was possibly a transient problem with the upgrade ... that has resolved itself.

If it does, then read the advice in [generic methodology to debug ordering cycles in systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193714/generic-methodology-to-debug-ordering-cycles-in-systemd), and when you are ready reboot into emergency mode ans see if you can see what is causing the cycle.

(My guess would be that you are either trying to export NFS file systems or mount NFS file systems too early in the startup sequence.)