# How can I solve this ordering cycle in a mount unit?

Tags: fedora, systemd, systemd-mount

Systemd-analyze is giving me different result depending on how much times I execute it, I'm doing `Systemd-analyze verify mnt-HDDs.mount` and getting:

```
local-fs.target: Found ordering cycle on HDDs-unlock.service/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on systemd-update-done.service/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
local-fs.target: Job systemd-update-done.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with local-fs.target/start
local-fs.target: Found ordering cycle on HDDs-unlock.service/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on systemd-journal-catalog-update.service/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
local-fs.target: Job systemd-journal-catalog-update.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with local-fs.target/start
local-fs.target: Found ordering cycle on HDDs-unlock.service/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on systemd-machine-id-commit.service/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
local-fs.target: Job systemd-machine-id-commit.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with local-fs.target/start
local-fs.target: Found ordering cycle on HDDs-unlock.service/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
local-fs.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with local-fs.target/start
```

```
sysinit.target: Found ordering cycle on plymouth-read-write.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on mnt-HDDs.mount/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on HDDs-unlock.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Job plymouth-read-write.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Found ordering cycle on local-fs.target/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on mnt-HDDs.mount/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on HDDs-unlock.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Job local-fs.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
```

```
sysinit.target: Found ordering cycle on systemd-update-done.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on HDDs-unlock.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Job systemd-update-done.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Found ordering cycle on systemd-machine-id-commit.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on HDDs-unlock.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Job systemd-machine-id-commit.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Found ordering cycle on systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on HDDs-unlock.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Job systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Found ordering cycle on plymouth-read-write.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on HDDs-unlock.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Job plymouth-read-write.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Found ordering cycle on local-fs.target/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on HDDs-unlock.service/start
sysinit.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Job local-fs.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
```

The units created directly involved in mnt-HDDs.mount:

mnt-HDDs.mount:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit for encripted device /mnt/HDDs
After=HDDs-unlock.service

[Mount]
Where=/mnt/HDDs
What=/dev/mapper/cryptHDDB
Type=btrfs
Options=noatime,compress-force=zstd,autodefrag,flushoncommit
```

HDDs-unlock.service

```
[Unit]
Description=HDDB and HDDC unlock
After=media-key.mount umount.target local-fs-pre.target
Before=local-fs.target
Conflicts=umount.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
KillMode=none
ExecStart=/usr/bin/HDDs-unlock.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/HDDs-lock.sh

[Install]
RequiredBy=mnt-HDDs.mount
```

media-key.mount

```
[Unit]
Description=HDDs key
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Mount]
Where=/media/key
What=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-SMI_USB_DISK_AA00000000065845-0:0
Options=ro,offset=952320
DirectoryMode=0400

[Install]
RequiredBy=HDDs-unlock.service
```

There is a `fstab` entry that mounts `/mnt/HDDs/@` that by automatic dependency calls for `mnt-HDDs.mount`, while rebooting in search for a solution it some times made my boot skip some services to the point of sometimes booting without network, any light on solving this ordering cycle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of searching (and a lot of revisits to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193854/125205) answer here in StackExchange) It ticked to me that this answer was about the same problem I was facing.

Basically mount units implicitly occur between local-fs-pre.targe and local-fs.targe, before basic.target, the problem is services get implicit Requires=basic.target and After=basic.target. the solution was to disable default dependencies:

```
[Unit]
....
DefaultDependencies=no
....
```

Comment: after two days of debugging I found this, thank you!